# react functional component let variable doesn't changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wrote functional component with react native.
but I'm in trouble because of a strange problem that seems to be a bug.

My purpose is changing variable in react functional component,
but variable not changed.

--I know It will be solved with change
`let isDirty` 
to
`cosnt [isDirty,setIsDirty] = useState(false)`

Why doesn't "isDirty" change when the handleTitleChange event occurs?

In pure js, it works very well

## update.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, CheckBox, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from 'react-navigation';
import TodoItem from '../models/todoItem';
import { updateItem } from '../DataProvider';

interface UpdateProps extends NavigationInjectedProps {
}

const Update: React.FC<UpdateProps> = (props) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(props.navigation.getParam("item") as TodoItem)
  let isDirty=false

  const handleSave=()=>{
    updateItem(item)
    
    if(isDirty&&props.navigation.state.params)
    {
      props.navigation.state.params.onUpdated(item);
    }
    props.navigation.goBack();
  }

  const handleCompleteChange= (value:boolean)=>{
    isDirty=true
    setItem({...item,isComplete:value})
  }

  const handleTitleChange=(txt:string)=>{
    isDirty=true
    setItem({...item,title:txt})
  }

  const handleContentChange=(txt:string)=>{
    isDirty=true
    setItem({...item,contents:txt})
  }
  
  return <View>
    <CheckBox value={item.isComplete} onValueChange={handleCompleteChange}></CheckBox>
    <TextInput defaultValue={item.title} onChangeText={handleTitleChange}></TextInput>
    <TextInput defaultValue={item.contents} onChangeText={handleContentChange}></TextInput>
    <Button title="Save" onPress={handleSave}></Button>
  </View>;
};

export default Update
```

## pure js

```
const Update = () => {
  let isDirty=false;

  const handleTitleChange=(txt)=>{
    console.log(isDirty);
    isDirty=true;
    console.log(isDirty);
  }
  handleTitleChange("a");
  handleTitleChange("b");
};


Update();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isDirty` is neither a `prop` nor a `state`. So it doesn't persist. On re-render, it will initialize back to `false`.

Make it a `state` instead.

```
const [isDirty, setDirty] = useState(false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
It was an short and easy explanation.

Answer (score 5):

When writing functional React code, `useRef` is the actual candidate to hold mutable values that holds the data and does not cause the rerender as well when using functional components.

Straight from the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

`useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.`

To solve your problem using `useRef`, you want to do this:

```
const isDirty = useRef(false);

...

const handleCompleteChange= (value:boolean)=>{
    isDirty.current = true;
    setItem({...item, isComplete:value})
}
```

The motivation React team has is to completely remove the class based concepts which would create confusions for developers.
Here is you can read about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation

Answer (score 0):

React does not re-render the component if any of the values other than the state changes, so, basically even if `isDirty` is updated, you won't see it in effect since the component doesn't realize there has been an update to one of its variables.

When the component re-renders, it executes the `let isDirty=false` again and this overwrites your update

converting as state like so, and updating the functions can solve your problem

```
const [isDirty, setIsDirty] = useState(false);

 const handleCompleteChange= (value:boolean)=>{
    setIsDirty(true);
    setItem({...item,isComplete:value})
  }

  const handleTitleChange=(txt:string)=>{
    setIsDirty(true);
    setItem({...item,title:txt})
  }

  const handleContentChange=(txt:string)=>{
    setIsDirty(true);
    setItem({...item,contents:txt})
  }
```

Read more about [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)